# Get type from string termname

Tags: scala, reflection, types, casting, type-conversion

Basically I want to read untyped JSON into a type that's specified by a string. Pseudocode.

```
def getObject(json: Json, typeString: String): typeOf(typeString) = extract[typeOf(typeString)](json)
```

`typeOf` is just some random thing that gives a type from a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is impossible without runtime reflection. With runtime reflection I would try the following:

- get the `Class[_]` by its name from `ClassLoader` - it would only work if you specified full name (with packages and everything) in `String`,
- then use something like Jackson which uses runtime reflection to (de)serialize things `new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, obtainedClass)`,
- obviously return type would be `Any` - theoretically you could use [path-dependent types](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/13/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-13-path-dependent-types.html) here, but personally I see little benefit.

However:

- it would be pretty fragile - any mismatch between JSON and class and it fails,
- you would have to pass full name of a class (again, fragile) - if you passed data from outside, that sounds like a potential security issue, if you passing data internally... why not using type class?
- if you need it for persistence... then you could persist it together with a discriminator, which you could use to provide right type class. (After all set of classes that you serialize is finite and could easily be traced). Then type safe approach with e.g. Circe would be possible.

Well I guess you could also change signature into:

```
def getObject[T: ClassTag](json: Json): T
```

or

```
def getObject[T](json: Json, clazz: Class[T]): T
```

and be sure that function return what you want. Getting Class[_] by its name and passing it reduces us to original solution.

EDIT:

To show an example of how to extract type from discriminator (pseudocode):

```
// store discriminator in DB
// use it to deserialize and dispatch with predefined function
def deserializeAndHandle(discriminator: String, json: String): Unit = discriminator match {
  case "my.package.A" => decode[my.package.A](json).map(handlerForA)
  case "my.package.B" => decode[my.package.B](json).map(handlerForB)
  case "my.package.C" => decode[my.package.C](json).map(handlerForC)
  case _              => 
}

deserializeAndHandle(discriminator, json)

// store discriminator in DB
// use it to deserialize to Object which can be pattern-matched later
def deserializeToObject(discriminator: String, json: String): Option[Any] = discriminator match {
  case "my.package.A" => decode[my.package.A](json).toOption
  case "my.package.B" => decode[my.package.B](json).toOption
  case "my.package.C" => decode[my.package.C](json).toOption
  case _              => None
}

deserializeToObject(discriminator, json) map {
  case a : A => ...
  case b : B => ...
  case c : C => ...
} getOrElse ???

// wrap unrelated types with sealed trait to make it sum type
// use sum type support of Circe
sealed trait Envelope
final case class EnvelopeA(a: A) extends Envelope
final case class EnvelopeB(b: B) extends Envelope
final case class EnvelopeA(c: C) extends Envelope
def deserializeEnveloped(json): Option[Envelope] = decode[Envelope](json).toOption

deserializeEnveloped(json) map {
  case EnvelopeA(a) => ...
  case EnvelopeB(b) => ...
  case EnvelopeC(c) => ...
} getOrElse ???
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by discriminator? My question is mostly for persistence reasons so...

Comment: Basically a metadata you put into your JSON, which on deserializations tells you which of several different decoders you should use. Standard example in e.g. Circe is sealed trait implemented by several case classes - Circe stores specific type in the JSON, next to its data and use it when it needs to deserialize it.

Comment: Currently I'm thinking about persisting the full type info in db.

Comment: Then you should be able to have exact `T` when you want to deserialize. There is no need to fetch all the data and then guess how to decode it when you can just fetch a sequence of JSONs of T type and use T decoder.

Comment: Not so? Type info is just a string. I can't get a Class[T], I can only get a Class[_] because T depends on the string.